# Python Plotly - Pivot created weird legend

Tags: python, plotly

I have a dataframe:

```
    Year    Type              Total
0   2005    Journal Article     635
1   2005    Book                173
2   2005    Book Chapter         27
3   2005    Consultancy Report    1
4   2005    Working Paper       329
.....
```

I then pivot it to get it into a suitable format (excuse the formatting of the pivot table, it is for illustrative purposes):

```
dfA = pd.pivot_table(dfPub, index=['Year'], columns=['Type'], fill_value=0)


    Total
Type    Book    Book Chapter    Book edited Conference Proceeding_Abstract  Consultancy Report  Journal Article Manual / Guide  Manual/Guide    Monograph   Other   Policy briefing_report  Scholarly edition   Systematic review   Technical Report    Technical Standard  Thesis  Working Paper
Year                                                                    
2005    173 27  0   174 1   635 0   0   0   7   0   0   0   81  0   1   329
2006    272 53  0   276 0   1078    0   0   0   14  2   0   0   91  0   11  532
2007    321 114 0   295 1   1588    0   0   0   5   2   0   0   139 0   10  548
2008    397 194 2   502 1   2237    0   0   4   19  4   0   0   142 0   10  580
2009    402 298 4   927 5   2876    0   0
```

When I create a stacked bar chart from it using plotly, I get:
[image]

What have I done wrong to get `''Total','` put before every `'Type'` in my legend? And is there a way to remove it? Thank you

I have tried editing the column names, but it isnt working:

```
dfA.rename(columns={"('Total', 'Book')":"Book", "('Total', 'Book Chapter')":"Book Chapter"})
list(dfA)

[('Total', 'Book'),
 ('Total', 'Book Chapter'),
 ('Total', 'Book edited'),
 ('Total', 'Conference Proceeding_Abstract'),
 ('Total', 'Consultancy Report'),
 ('Total', 'Journal Article'),
 ('Total', 'Manual / Guide'),
 ('Total', 'Manual/Guide'),
 ('Total', 'Monograph'),
 ('Total', 'Other'),
 ('Total', 'Policy briefing_report'),
 ('Total', 'Scholarly edition'),
 ('Total', 'Systematic review'),
 ('Total', 'Technical Report'),
 ('Total', 'Technical Standard'),
 ('Total', 'Thesis'),
 ('Total', 'Working Paper')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the table which you provided for the plotly has two column headers. Years as first column header for the whole table and the correct column headers as second, hence it has tagged total for every field. Try rename the column headers, or drop the column headers and rename it.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I will give it a go!

Comment: I tried renaming the columns but it isnt working. I have edited my question. Hum :)

Comment: Rename the column with this below code, dfA.columns = ['Book','Book Chapter', 'Book edited','Conference Proceeding_Abstract','Consultancy Report','Journal Article','Manual / Guide','Manual/Guide','Monograph','Other','Policy briefing_report','Scholarly edition','Systematic review','Technical Report','Technical Standard','Thesis','Working Paper']